# how to connect to the remote server through json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

i tried connecting the json data through ajax.but getting lots of problem,that cross domain,receving port does not exist.can anyone tell me other  method how to post the data to the server by using getjson method or other any working method.

```
requestNumber = JSONRequest.post(
    "https://json.penzance.org/request",
    {
        user: "doctoravatar@yahoo.com",
        t: "vlIj",
        zip: 94089,
        forecast: 7
    },
    function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
        if (value) {
            processResponse(value);
        } else {
            processError(exception);
        }
    }
);
```

in this function i m not getting anything.so pls anyone can help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have insurmountable problems using AJAX to fetch JSON data; it is a very common method for fetching data from external servers. As such, I would advise you to resolve the problems with AJAX rather than trying to use another method.

You'll find some pointers below about how to fix the two problems you mentioned.

### Same Origin Policy

To resolve the same origin policy problem, look into **CORS** (Cross Origin Resource Sharing):

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
>
> http://enable-cors.org/

Or **JSON-P** (I would advise that you look at CORS rather than JSON-P, for security reasons)

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

### Receiving Port Does Not Exist

As for the receiving port not existing, that sounds like you are either sending the request to the wrong address or that the receiving server is incorrectly configured.

Comment: @user3148543 I will help you, but it will have to be later this afternoon; I'm afraid I don't have any time at the moment.

Comment: ..okk but tell me today only.cant go ahead in my project because of this.

Comment: @user3148543 An AJAX request simply makes an ordinary page request to a particular URL. In order for this request to return JSON data, you will have to create a server side script (in whichever server-side language you're using) that serves the JSON data. For example, in PHP you would use json_encode() http://uk1.php.net/json_encode

Comment: okk.but i m getting this error json parsed failed error?can u tell me why i am getting this?actually its not going inside success function.so tell me about this.

Comment: The javascript you have above is fine, I ran a check in JSFiddle and it was running successfully. However, I must ask, what are you trying to do with the JSON? It was my understanding from your original question that the JSON data was being retrieved by the javascript function, not created. Why are you trying to generate JSON data rather than retrieve it?

Comment: @user3148543 In order to resolve the error, I would have to see the server side script and javascript code which is creating the request. If you amend your question with both these scripts, then I'll have a look.